# How to handle calling Ajax function within another Ajax function

Tags: jquery

I am doing an Ajax call from my first function named displayingRestaurantsForLabel which is calling another  function by name showRestaurantDetailsByLocation .

Now as per me requirement i need to make a Ajax call based on the date recievied  inside the showRestaurantDetailsByLocation

Please let me know how to handle this ??

This is my code

```
function displayingRestaurantsForLabel(id,locationname)
{
    var locationname = locationname;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url+'/OMS/oms1/chdfavoriterestntsbylocation?cust_id='+cust_id+'&locationname='+locationname,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        beforeSend: function()
        { 
           $("#loader").show(); 
        }, 
        complete: function() 
        { 
            $("#loader").hide();
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var response = JSON.stringify(response);
            if(response!='')
            {
            showRestaurantDetailsByLocation(response,locationname,id);
            }
        },
        error :
        {
            alert('Into error ');
        }
        }
    });
}




function showRestaurantDetailsByLocation(response, locationname,id) {
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    var responsedata = JSON.stringify(response);
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var temp_variable = '';
    var vendor_accpeted ='';
       var dateres = response[i].date;

       // Need to call a Ajax call here based on the date recievied . 
     }

}
```

It is actually

Ajax Call waiting for the response of another Ajax Call?

please let me know how to resolve this .

Comment: Promise http://api.jquery.com/promise/ is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

There is one extra property is missing async:false in your ajax call

```
async:false
```